# It looks like Bundler could not find a gem. Maybe you didn't install all the gems that this application needs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, amazon-ec2, passenger

I am deployed rails application in apache using passenger gem, I am getting below error. followed the link to deploy rails application
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-with-passenger-and-apache-on-ubuntu-14-04

Error:-

```
  It looks like Bundler could not find a gem. Maybe you didn't install all the gems that this application needs.  
To install your gems, please run:

    bundle install  


      If that didn't work, then the problem is probably caused by your application being run under a different environment  
than it's supposed to. Please check the following:

        Is this app supposed to be run as the www-data user?
        Is this app being run on the correct Ruby interpreter? Below you will see which Ruby interpreter Phusion Passenger attempted to use.
```

trace:-

```
        -------- The exception is as follows: -------
        Your bundle is locked to activesupport (4.2.6), but that version could not be found in any of the sources listed in your Gemfile.   
    If you haven't changed sources, that means the author of activesupport (4.2.6) has removed it.   
    You'll need to update your bundle to a different version of activesupport (4.2.6) that hasn't been removed in order to install. (Bundler::GemNotFound)

          /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/definition.rb:179:in `rescue in specs'
          /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/definition.rb:173:in `specs'
          /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/definition.rb:233:in `specs_for'
          /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/definition.rb:222:in `requested_specs'
          /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:118:in `block in definition_method'
          /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:19:in `setup'
          /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler.rb:99:in `setup'
          /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/setup.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
          /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
          /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
          /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:430:in `activate_gem'
          /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:297:in `block in run_load_path_setup_code'
          /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:435:in `running_bundler'
          /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:296:in `run_load_path_setup_code'
          /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:100:in `preload_app'
          /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:156:in `<module:App>'
          /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:30:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'

      /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<main>'
```

**Update**

```
    source 'https://rubygems.org'
    # Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
    gem 'rails', '4.2.6'
    # Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
    gem 'sqlite3'
    # Use SCSS for stylesheets
    gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
    # Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
    gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
    # Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
    gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
    # See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
    # gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

    # Use jquery as the JavaScript library
    gem 'jquery-rails'
    # Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
    gem 'turbolinks'
    # Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
    gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
    # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
    gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
    gem "unicorn"
    gem "thin"
    gem "passenger"  
    group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
```

Comment: Try `bundle update`

Comment: did you run `bundle` or `bundle install`?

Comment: yes, but same problem

Comment: can you post your gem file too? in particular the place you specify rails, or activesupport. and did you do any `gem install` instead of `bundle install`? it seems the gem you are trying to install required a different version of `active_support`, which is locked at version 4.2.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to install rails 4.2.6 gem

```
gem install rails -v 4.2.6
```

or

```
sudo gem install rails -v 4.2.6
```

Answer (score 0):

A step seems to be missing in the tutorial, run

```
gem install bundler
```

Then you should be able to run

```
bundle install
```